# Don't show section heading, PDF instead

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, pdfpages

I want to make a normal section, shown in the table of contents with hyperref enabled, but instead of section heading I want to insert a PDF. I already tried to just hide the section heading by setting it's size to 0pt but this resulted in a blank page followed by my PDF.

For a little bit more context: The PDF contains a bill of materials wich has to be visible in the table of contents with the correct page number linked.

Including the PDF as an image also isn't an option because the document has to be searchable.

---

My code currently looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Bill of Materials}
\includepdf{billofmaterials.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71307/hyperref-to-external-pdf-that-will-open-at-particular-label) might be a guideline to you.

Comment: if the pdf you are including is less than a page use `\includegraphics` (it still gets included as searchable pdf text not as an image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use option `addtotoc` to add entries to the TOC.

```
\includepdf[
  addtotoc={1, section, 1, Bill of Materials, sec:bom}
]{billofmaterials.pdf}
```

I do not recommend to use option `pagecommand` like in the accepted answer. More often than not such solutions will break if you include a multipage PDF, because `pagecommand` is evaluated on each page.

Comment: Thank you, this solution is definitley more elegant. I would have inserted only one page per PDF anyways, but for people who would like to insert PDFs with more pages, this looks like the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I now found a solution with the help of these two articles:

[Include PDF and Section into one site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261210/260932)
and
[Hide part and chapter headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16068/260932)

My code now looks like this and it does the trick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\newcommand*\Hide{
\titleformat{\section}
  {}{}{0pt}{}
}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\includepdf[pagecommand={\Hide \section{Bill of Materials} \thispagestyle{empty}},scale=1]{billofmaterials.pdf}

\end{document}
```

It's probably not the most elegant solution, but it works for me.